# Symmetries of lines incident with orthocenter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $ l$ be a line passing through the orthocenter of $ABC$ which intersects the lines  $BC$, $AC$, and $AB$ in points $A_1$, $B_1$, and $C_1$, respectively. Assume the lines $l_1$, $l_2$, and $l_3$ are, respectively, the reflections of $l$ with respect to lines  $BC$, $AC$, and $AB$. I guess that $l_1$, $l_2$, and $l_3$ are concurrent.

[image: LineThroughH]

My observations:

If $l_2$, and $l_3$ intersect at $K$, then line vertex $A$ would be incident with the bisector $KA$ of angle $\angle B_1KC_1$. Similar results are deduced for vertices $B$ and $C$ of triangle $ABC$....

Thanks for any hint for the continuation of the above argument leading to a (probable) proof for my claim, or  any other suggestion if it is false.

Comment: Please provide a graphic (using Geogebra, Desmos...) in order we understand what you mean.

Comment: Please introduce all the points needed, including the "corresponding vertex", use full notations for the lines, and specify which reflection is taken for each height, with respect to which line. Then the story seems to happen in the three dimensional space, since "any line" in some plane containing the orthocenter is also introduced. We have this "any line" to jump in the role of (one of all) altitudes. It is really hard to understand the statement. Then please state one clear question, this is in the spirit of the site, and please show the own effort to solve the issue...

Comment: Yes, the three symmetric lines of any straight line other than the altitudes of a triangle, which passes through its orthocentre, are concurrent, but not at a vertex of the triangle.

Comment: @YNK Thanks for the comment. I need a suggestion for the start to prove this claim (Ceva's Theorem or any other thing).

Comment: I think all those who want to render their help to you to solve this problem are waiting for you to do a favour by at least providing a sketch to picturesquely describe your problem statement to clear some doubts they have.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify my guess. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have proof, but I wrote a small program to check if the reflected line across the three sides of the triangle are concurrent, and my program confirms that it is true.  I checked this with several orientation of the line and the reflected lines are always concurrent.

Comment: @karparvar: Not only are the three lines concurrent, they meet at a point on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @Blue: Would you please give a proof therof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof given below uses Wallace-Simson theorem and several properties of the Wallace-Simson line of a point with respect to a triangle. This theorem asserts that the feet of the perpendiculars dropped from an arbitrary point on the circumcircle of a triangle to its sides are collinear. The line that passes through the mentioned feet is called the Wallace-Simson line. Three of the many properties of this line are,

$\quad\space\space\text{i.$\enspace$The Wallace-Simson line of a vertex of the triangle is the altitude of the triangle dropped}\\\qquad\enspace \text{ from that vertex.}$

$\quad\space\text{ii.$\enspace$If $P$ and $Q$ are points on the circumcircle of the triangle, then the angle between the}\\\qquad\space \text{ Wallace-Simson lines of $P$ and $Q$ is half the angle of the arc $PQ$.}$.

$\quad\text{iii.$\enspace$If $P$ is a point on the circumcircle of the triangle, its Wallace-Simson line passes through}\\\qquad\space \text{ the midpoint of the line segment joining $P$ and the orthocentre of the triangle.}$

[image: Reflections]

As shown in the $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, line $\pmb{l}$ is an arbitrary line which passes through the orthocentre $H$ of an arbitrary triangle $ABC$  It cuts the sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ of the $\triangle ABC$ at $A_1$, $B_1$, and $C_1$ respectively.

For the time being, assume that we used properties (i) and (ii) to geometrically determine the location of point $K$, so that its Wallace-Simson line is parallel to the line $\pmb{l}$, which intersects the sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ of the $\triangle ABC$ at $U$, $V$, and $W$ respectively. The corresponding geometrical construction is given at the end of this text.

According to the property (iii), point $M$ is the midpoint of $HK$. We complete the scenario by joining points $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$, $U$, $V$, and $W$ to $K$. The Wallace-Simson line meets $A_1K$, $B_1K$, and $C_1K$ at $D$, $E$, and $F$, respectively. Now, our aim is to show that $A_1K$, $B_1K$, and $C_1K$ are the reflections of line $\pmb{l}$ on the sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ of the $\triangle ABC$ respectively. For brevity, we let $\measuredangle WKC_1 =\phi$.

Consider the $\triangle C_1KH$. By construction, $HC_1$ is parallel to $MF$. Therefore, since $M$ is the midpoint of $HK$, it follows from the converse of midpoint theorem, that $C_1F=FK$, i.e., $F$ is the midpoint of $C_1K$.

According to the Wallace-Simson theorem, $KW$ is perpendicular to $AB$ and that makes the $\triangle C_1WK$ a right-angled triangle.
$${\large{\pmb{\therefore}}}\quad\space\measuredangle KC_1W =90^o-\phi.$$

Since $F$ is the midpoint of the hypotenuse of this triangle, we have, $FW=C_1F=FK$, which makes $\triangle WFC_1$ an isosceles triangle.
$${\large{\pmb{\therefore}}}\quad\space \measuredangle C_1WF = \measuredangle FC_1W = 90^o-\phi.$$

Since line $\pmb{l}$ is parallel to the Wallace-Simson line, we shall write,
$$\measuredangle WC_1G=\measuredangle C_1WF=90^o-\phi.$$

Since, $\measuredangle WC_1G=\measuredangle C_1WF$, $AB$ is the angle bisector of $\measuredangle KC_1G$.

Applying similar reasoning to appropriate geometrical objects in the diagram, one can prove $A_1K$ and $B_1K$ are the reflections of line $\pmb{l}$ on the sides $BC$ and $CA$ respectively

$\underline{\text{The Construction }}:$

We describe here concisely how to locate the point on the circumcircle of a given triangle $ABC$, the Wallace-Simson line of which is parallel to a
given line $FG$.

[image: WallaceSimsonLine]

We drop the perpendicular $AD$ from the vertex $A$ of the $\triangle ABC$ to its opposite side $BC$. We do this because of the property (i). In other words, we know that $A$ is on the circumcircle of the $\triangle ABC$ and its Wallace-Simson line is the constructed altitude $AD$. Therefore, $A$ serves as the base of our construction. Assume that $AD$ meets the given line $FG$ at $E$ while the two lines making an angle $\theta$ as shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$.

After drawing the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, we join its center $O$ to $A$. According to the property (ii), we need to find a point $P$ on the circumcircle so that the chord $AP$ must subtend an angle equal to $2\theta$ at the center $O$. This can be achieved by constructing the radius $OP$ so that $\measuredangle POA=2\theta$. After drawing perpendiculars from $P$ to any two sides of the $\triangle ABC$, join their feet to obtain the sought Wallace-Simson line $ST$ of point $P$.